# Execute script that uses my local package - ImportErrors

Tags: python, dockerfile, python-venv, python-install

My project was up-and-running for a while running in a kubernetes container... until, I decided to "clean-up" my use of the `sys.add` calls that I had at the top of my modules. This included describing my dependencies in `pyproject.toml`, and all-together ditching `setup.py`; it imported setup tools, called `setup()` `when __main__`.

The design intent is not to run anything in `/tnc/app` as a script.  But rather, a collection of modules, or a package.  The only part of the codebase that serves as a `__main__` is the `api.py` file.  It initializes and fires-up flask.

#### Implementation

I have a lean deployment setup that consists of the following:

1. the core library in `/opt/venv`
2. my package `/app/tnc`
3. and the entry point `/app/bin/api`

I kick-off the flask app with: `python /app/bin/api`.

The *build* takes place in the `python:3.11-slim` docker image. Here I install the recommended gcc and specify the following in the dockerfile:

```
-- build
RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"
COPY pyproject.toml project.toml
RUN pip3 install -e .  -- << aside: better would be to use python -m pip3 install -e .
```

I then copy the following from the build into my *runtime* image.

```
-- runtime
ENV PATH "/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"
ENV PYTHONPATH "/opt/venv/bin:/app/tnc"
COPY --chown=appuser:appuser bin bin
COPY --chown=appuser:appuser tnc tnc
COPY --chown=appuser:appuser config.py config.py
COPY --from=builder /opt/venv/ /opt/venv
```

As I mentioned, in the kubernetes deployment I fire-up the container with:

```
command: ["python3"]
args: ["bin/api"]
```

#### My observations working to find the solution

Firing up the container in such a way that I can run the python REPL:

- `import flask` generates `AttributeError ...replace(' -> None', '')`
- *remove* `/app/tnc` from the `PYTHONPATH`, `import flask` generates `ModuleNotFound ... no tnc`

##### `AttributeError ...replace(' -> None', '')`

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .test import Client as Client
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/test.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .sansio.multipart import Data
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/werkzeug/sansio/multipart.py", line 19, in <module>
    class Preamble(Event):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dataclasses.py", line 1175, in wrap
    return _process_class(cls, init, repr, eq, order, unsafe_hash,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dataclasses.py", line 1093, in _process_class
    str(inspect.signature(cls)).replace(' -> None', ''))
AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'signature'
```

#### `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tnc'`

```bash
appuser@tnc-py-deployment-set-1:/app$ echo $PYTHONPATH
/opt/venv/bin
appuser@tnc-py-deployment-set-1:/app$ echo $PATH
/opt/venv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
appuser@tnc-py-deployment-set-1:/app$ python -m /app/bin/api
/opt/venv/bin/python: No module named /app/bin/api
appuser@tnc-py-deployment-set-1:/app$ python /app/bin/api
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/bin/api", line 12, in <module>
    from tnc.s3 import S3Session
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tnc'
```

#### The project structure

```
├── bin
│   └── api
├── config.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── tnc
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── data
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── download.py
    │   ├── field_types.py
    │   └── storage_providers
    ├── errors.py
    ├── inspect
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── etl_time_index.py
    ├── test
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── test_end-to-end.py
    ├── utils.py
    └── www
        ├── __init__.py
        └── routes
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── feedback.py
            ├── livez.py
            └── utils.py
```

##### pyproject.toml

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["./"]
exclude = [ "res", "notes" ]

dependencies = [ ... with version specs ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I have to shout-out to the `pyproject.toml` + `setuptools` team: the [documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/index.html) and implementation has gotten good.  It allowed me to get a lot more specific and "deterministic" :)) about my setup.  Not to mention, a bit more aggressive in the build process.

#### Fixing the "not found" errors

The fix included the following:

1. updated the `pyproject.toml` with the following

```ini
[tool.setuptools.package-dir]
tnc = "tnc"
bin = "bin"

# entry point (not required but is ergonomic)
[project.scripts]
run-api = "bin.api:main"
```

I included a `__init__` to mark each submodule.

2. Perhaps not required, but I moved the `config.py` file into the `bin` directory.  This location captured my design intent.  Changes to the `api.py` file...

```py
# instantiate the config object using a string ref to the config.py
app.config.from_object("bin.config.DevelopmentConfig")
...

# added a def main() to enable the option of specifying an entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    app.run(host=app.config['HOST'], port=app.config['PORT'])

def main():
    """ if using entrypoint script """
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    app.run(host=app.config['HOST'], port=app.config['PORT'])
```

3. In the Dockerfile I set the `PYTHONPATH` env value to "/app", the location of the `tnc` and `bin` directories.  By no means a best practice, but in this case, given my determination to have `bin` separate from `tnc`, the only way that made sense.  This use case seemed the right way to go.

#### Improved build process

Finally, while there are a few well known techniques to maximize the reuse of the cache when building the docker image, I wanted to call out how easy it was to know precisely what was going on during the build, made possible by the latest `setuptool` configured with `pyproject.toml`.

A. It was trivial to first run the build using empty stub for where the app code would eventually go.

```ini
# pyproject.dependencies.toml
packages = ["tnc"]
```

... paired with the 2 phased build (the image is an official docker python image)

```
# Make sure to use the venv from the python base img:
RUN python -m venv /opt/venv
ENV PATH="/opt/venv/bin:$PATH"

# phase 1: dependency build using an empty project dir
COPY pyproject.dependencies.toml pyproject.toml
RUN mkdir tnc
RUN pip3 install .

# phase 2: full and final build
COPY bin bin
COPY tnc tnc
COPY pyproject.toml pyproject.toml
RUN pip3 install .
```

B. It was clear what to copy from the now consolidated build artifacts, into my image used for distribution

```
COPY --from=builder --chown=appuser:appuser /app/build/lib/tnc tnc
COPY --from=builder --chown=appuser:appuser /app/build/lib/bin bin
COPY --from=builder --chown=root:root /opt/venv/ /opt/venv
```

In the kube deployment, despite being able call the entry point configured using `pyproject.toml`, I chose to call the `api.py` as a script.

```yaml
# in the kube deployment for the image
command: ["python"]
args: ["/app/bin/api.py"]
```

#### Conclusion

I have an improved design that no longer includes "ad-hoc" calls to `sys.path, nor resorts to "polluting" the` PYTHONPATH`.  The single entry I now have,` /app`, conveys an important design choice: wanting to have the entry point be in a separate root directory.